# Finding intersected rows in different columns and label them

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for solution about how to correctly label intersect rows in a data frame.

Such that

```
df = data.frame(id=c("good","bad","ugly","dirty","clean","frenzy"),di=c("good",2,"good","dirty",4,"ugly"))

> df
      id    di
1   good  good
2    bad     2
3   ugly  good
4  dirty dirty
5  clean     4
6 frenzy  ugly
```

I would like to create column name `match` and if there is common intersected row values label them as `intersected` else `no.intersect`.

I tried

```
df%>%
  mutate(match=ifelse(isTRUE(intersect(id,di)),"intersected","no.intersect"))
```

and it outputs

```
      id    di        match
1   good  good no.intersect
2    bad     2 no.intersect
3   ugly  good no.intersect
4  dirty dirty no.intersect
5  clean     4 no.intersect
6 frenzy  ugly no.intersect
```

although there is an intersect in row 1 and 4.

Comment: Do you mean rows where `id` and `di` are the same?

Comment: @AntoniosK yes exactly!

Comment: Try this: `library(dplyr);

df = data.frame(id=c("good","bad","ugly","dirty","clean","frenzy"),di=c("good",2,"good","dirty",4,"ugly"), stringsAsFactors = F);

df %>% mutate(match = ifelse(id == di,"intersected","no.intersect"))`. You can use an equality condition instead of intersect, but you need to have non-factor variables

Comment: @AntoniosK Great! it worked. Please sent your answer as solution!

Comment: Updated my answer below with an example of how to use `intersect` correctly (if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataframe
# (non factor variables)
df = data.frame(id=c("good","bad","ugly","dirty","clean","frenzy"),
                di=c("good",2,"good","dirty",4,"ugly"), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

# check equaity of values at each row
df %>% mutate(match = ifelse(id == di, "intersected", "no.intersect"))

#       id    di        match
# 1   good  good  intersected
# 2    bad     2 no.intersect
# 3   ugly  good no.intersect
# 4  dirty dirty  intersected
# 5  clean     4 no.intersect
# 6 frenzy  ugly no.intersect
```

Also, if you want to use `intersect` you can use it like this:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(match = ifelse(length(intersect(id,di)) > 0, "intersected", "no.intersect")) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   id     di    match       
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>       
# 1 good   good  intersected 
# 2 bad    2     no.intersect
# 3 ugly   good  no.intersect
# 4 dirty  dirty intersected 
# 5 clean  4     no.intersect
# 6 frenzy ugly  no.intersect
```

Because `intersect` is not vectorized (so you need `rowwise`) and it doesn't return TRUE or FALSE (so you can't use `isTRUE`). It will return the actual value if there is a match, or nothing if there's no match.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compare for equality between id and di, try:

```
df %>% mutate(match = ifelse(id == di, "intersected", "no.intersect"))
```